# transforming postfix expression to expression tree C

Tags: c, data-structures, expression-trees, postfix-notation

I tried making a function which transforms a string in postfix notation to an expression tree. But i cant figure out what is wrong with it.

```
node_t* expressionTree(char *str,stack_t *p2)
{
    int i; 
    t_node *arv,*left,*right;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            arv = arv_insert(str[i],NULL,NULL);
            stack_push(p2,arv);
        }
        else{
            left = stack_pop(p2);
            if (stack_empty(p2)) {
                arv = arv_insert(str[i],left,NULL);

            }
            else{
                right = stack_pop(p2);
                arv = arv_insert(str[i],left,right);

            }
            stack_push(p2,arv);
        }
    }
    return p2->arr[p2->topo];
}
```

If i pass the expression 54*3*+1- the postorder returned from the tree generated above is 1345**+-

Comment: Sorry, the expression i'm passing is 54*3*+1-

Comment: You should click [Edit] and change the question, rather than posting a correction in the comments.

Comment: `54*3*+1-` and `1345**+-` give the same operations, on the same numbers, in the same order -- just with the left and right operands reversed for each operation.

Comment: I dont really get it, what should i change in order to reverse it then?

Comment: Maybe switch the left and right child nodes around when you add an operator to the tree..